# One div on my website is higher than the other, despite identical CSS. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://christianselig.com

Of my two header images, one is about 10px higher or so but I can't figure out what's causing it. I've crawled my code but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: At least you could stop editing that page so people that are really willing to help you could have some time to do so. Please read the FAQ and welcome to SO

Comment: they're absolutely identhical in Firefox

Comment: if you are changing your website, reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Bad form to post a link to an external website with code that may change instead of posting a jsfiddle or the code.

Comment: Make sure you do server side validation on your form once it actually does something. Your javascript validation can both be bypassed and browser support for HTML5 forms is very patchy. Check out http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's an extra line break in the link on the left.